# wordpress website host price and security

Tags: security, hosting, hosting-recommendation

I am creating a website which I need to host. If I buy a domain from one of the website hosting companies do they provide security from attacks or should I some how take care of it? If I have to take care of it how should I ensure that my website (developed using wordpress) is secure?

Also could you suggest some reliable web hosting companies?